# How to create a masking effect in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, slice, mask

how would I create an effect like the one in the link in unity with c#? i would like to control the reveal of a 3d object with a slider. is it possible? some kind of mask i assume?

[via GIPHY](https://giphy.com/gifs/AFoRg2rphquBNrQrP6)

Comment: Please don't just ask "How to I do x" But present problems you are facing when making x, providing errors, code and things you have already tried yourself.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

That said after a quick google i found this,which sounds like what you want. https://answers.unity.com/questions/316064/can-i-obscure-an-object-using-an-invisible-object.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this specifically with c#, you will need to use the [Mesh](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.html) api to generate a sphere mesh, then modify the verts to remove the ones you don't want to display. A much easier solution would be to use a fragment shader to not draw the pixels that were outside the boundaries you define. This would be much more versatile as well, it would apply to any mesh you provided to it.

[Discarding pixels based on world position](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1242982/discard-pixels-from-fragment-shader-based-on-scree.html) shows how to get a similar effect.